# Modeling data in Neo4J - splitting node - translation

Tags: neo4j, split, translation, modeling, multilingual

[image address nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJFAJ.png)

Is it recommended to split up an address node into three nodes:
- address (street + nbr)
- city
- country

Would it be easier to wright queries searching events that took place in certain cities/ countries?
I was also wondering if I wanted the address translations stored as well in Neo4J, if I should do it like the image above.

Comment: I don't get why this question is put on hold for being primarily opinion-based. I have never modeled a Neo4J Graph DB before and simply want to ask how I should build things whithout making it too complicated. It would be nice to know more about the reason why somebody wants this question closed. Very helpfull!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you model your graph depends on how you will want to query your graph. Splitting up location in more nodes is recommended if you want to do searches by country/city/address. Now if you will not groupby results by address, you do not need to create a separate node for address and you can save it as a property on Person node. This is what I usually do, because I mostly do not deal with many persons on same location, so no need for address node. As for saving translations it also depends if you will ever use them in a query. If so you can save them as a property on the City/Country in case you need them. The picture below shows
[image] how I typically approach this problem. Note that I also use a single relationship type throughout location tree. If you want to filter people by living on the same address then you can add the address node also.[image]

Comment: In this case there would need to be an edge between Person and City, and an edge between Person and Country. Because a streetname can appear in more than one City or Country. The same for cities appearing in more than one country. Otherwise we wouldn't know in which country the person lives if City is connected to more than one Country node.

Comment: If I would make the model like this I will be able to write queries to see which person is connected to which person via their similar address, but I guess I won't have a nice visual result that makes it instantly clear which Person nodes are connected this way.

Comment: You can create relationship between people living on the same address with this query. `MATCH (p:Person)-[:IS_IN]->(a)<[:IS_IN]-(p1:Person) MERGE (p)-[:SAME_ADDRESS]-(p1)`

Comment: Thanks, good idea. I'll consider that. I guess the easiest would be if I had the coordinates of every address and put that in one node. Then I could connect the node with the coordinates with the city and country node.

Answer (score 0):

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ubyF.png)

I actually want to have statistics on people of certain cities/countries that attented certain events the most. So I suppose it is best to keep city and country in a seperate node. But I also want to connect people living on the same address. Then I suppose, it's best to keep city and country in the same address node. Can I do both (like in the example image here above)?

Comment: it is never a good idea to create a separate node and also save it as a property. I added and example if you have addresses also